# @PostConstruction tries to initilize scoped service - not autowired in the method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scope, postconstruct

I have a method with @PostConstruct annotation which uses autowired service

```
@Service
public ServiceWithPostConstruct{

private AutowiredService autowiredService;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceWithPostConstruct(AutowiredService autowiredService) {
        this.autowiredService= autowiredService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomething() {
    autowiredService.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

AutowiredService declaration

```
@Component
public class AutowiredService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AutowiredService .class);

    private static final String SUCCESS_CODE = "0";

    private RestOperations restOperations;

    @Autowired
    public AutowiredService (RestOperations restOperations) {
        this.restOperations = restOperations;
    }
///
}
```

somewhere else in the code, I have a completely unrelated component, which has a scope = request

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ScopedService{
}
```

and listener in web.xml

> org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener

this service works correctly, where it is used.

However while starting the application, I get the following error:

> 12-Dec-2017 13:24:15.221 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'controller' defined in file
>   [controller.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'serviceWithPostConstruct':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.scopedService': Scope
>   'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a
>   scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a
>   singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of
>   the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within
>   a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
>   running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case,
>   use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the
>   current request.

This error might have been understood if I would be autowiring the mentioned ScopedService. But clearly I am not. I don't understand, why this @PostConstruct method has anything to do with ScopedService. 
If I remove the @PostConstruct annotation problem disappears. And the ScopedService works everywhere as intended, in Singletons as well. However, only if I get rid of the @PostConstruct  annotation.  Unfortunately, I need to keep it.

I am certain that the use of autowired service in doSomething() method is the core of the problem, if I remove the autowired service, the application starts correctly.
It seems, that because of this @PostConstruct method, Spring checks ALL services, and when it comes to the ScopedService (the only component with scope=request) it recognizes that in that moment there is no HttpRequest and throws an error. Why? It is not connected in any way with that ScopedService.

What can be done about that?
I will appreciate any ideas.

Comment: AutowiredService doesn't have a dependency on ScopedService?

Comment: Well the `autowiredService` isn't really `autowired`, is it? Get rid of the constructor and declare the service member as `@Autowired private AutowiredService autowiredService;`.

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski no, it does not - completely unrelated

Comment: @daniu Doesn't the "@Autowired" annotation at constructor do the same job as a separate "@Autowired" setter?

Comment: hmmm going through the documentation it looks like you're right, I never used it that way...

Comment: @daniu i changed it anyway to your suggestion, unfortunately the same error

Comment: Well in the Exception trace, there's also mention of a bean `scopedTarget`. Where does that come from? And maybe show the `AutowiredService`  declaration.

Comment: Instead of using JSR-250's `@PostConstruct`, can you try using Spring's InitializingBean interface? It shouldn't do the trick but you have nothing to lose...

Comment: the "scopedTarget" comes from the fact, that ScopedService has a declared scope - as explained here http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/45681-spring-session-scope-related-what-is-scopedtarget

Comment: @NicoVanBelle the thing is, I really don't want to remove "@PostConstruct" as it is a part of some old integration with outside application - I added the ScopedService. but I will try if nothing else would work, thanks

Comment: @daniu I added the AutowiredService in the original question

Comment: @Maki You don't change the logic at all as it does exactly the same. `@PostConstruct` is a JEE standard, InitializingBean is Spring-only. So it's safe to replace one over the other unless you mix them (which you don't) AND the order of execution is important

Comment: You did leave out the `dosomethingElse()` method and `RestOperations` which might be using the scopedService . Anyway, you say "It seems, that because of this @PostConstruct method, Spring checks ALL services" but a RequestScope bean is only created at request time, so you must have a place in the autowiring chain where it gets used or Spring wouldn't check.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle ok, thanks, will try

Comment: @daniu I get it. It is just my assumption - it really doesn't make sense to me, that Spring would check something "just because", but as I wrote: "it seems" - it is weird, I agree. As for the RestOperations it is a Spring interface org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations, i will add the method in post in a moment

Comment: @majki, there is but one RestOperations implementation and it is Spring's `RestTemplate` so inject that one as everybody does..